# Regex for any number of words before new line

Tags: python, regex

I parsed some text in paragraph which I want to split out to insert into table.

The string looks like:

`["Some text unsure how many numbers or if any special charectors etc. But I don't really care I just want all the text in this string \n 123 some more text (50% and some more text) \n"]`

What I want do is split out the first string of text before the new line, as it is - whatever that might be. I started by trying this `[A-Za-z]*\s*[A-Za-z]*\s*` but soon realised that was not going to cut it as the text in this string is variable.

I then want to take the numbers in the second string, which the following seems to do:

```
\d+
```

Then finally I want to get the percentage in the second string, which the following seems to work for:

```
\d+(%)+
```

I'm planning on using these in a function, but am struggling to compile the regex for the first part? I'm also wondering if the regexs I have for the second 2 parts are the most efficient?

Update: Hopefully this makes it a bit more clear?

Input:

`[‘ The first chunk of text \n 123 the stats I want (25% the percentage I want) \n The Second chunk of text \n 456 the second stats I want (50% the second percentage I want) \n The third chunk of text \n 789 the third stats I want (75% the third percentage) \n The fourth chunk of text \n 101 The fourth stats (100% the fourth percentage) \n]`

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: The parentheses in `\d+(%)+` are completely superfluous.  Do you really intend to allow more than one percent sign?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want a regex if you are using python ?
Wouldnt `yourstring.split('\n')[0]` do the trick ?

Comment: You want anything before the \n right? Just do .*\n. Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: @mkingsbu I want all the words from the even new lines and numbers from the odd new lines - if that makes sense?

Comment: I see. Yes, in that case as others have mentioned, I think a regex is the wrong way to go about this. A regex would have to have all the logic contained in itself, which could be difficult depending on the size of the file. I don't know Python, but I know how I'd do this in Bash. I'd make a C style for loop and read the variable into it. If the count was even, then I'd append it to the even matrix, and if it were odd I'd append it there.  Perhaps it would be better to ask a slightly broader question about what you're trying to do with these data?

Comment: I updated the question, which should make it a bit more clear? Ultimately, I am going to store it in CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2 first lines

You can use `split` to get the two first lines :

```
import re

data = ["Some text unsure how many numbers or if any special charectors etc. But I don't really care I just want all the text in this string \n 123 some more text (50% and some more text) \n"]

first_line, second_line = data[0].split("\n")[:2]
print first_line
# Some text unsure how many numbers or if any special charectors etc. But I don't really care I just want all the text in this string

digit_match = re.search('\d+(?![\d%])', second_line)
if digit_match:
    print digit_match.group()
    # 123

percent_match = re.search('\d+%', second_line)
if percent_match:
    print percent_match.group()
    # 50%
```

Note that if the percentage is written before the other number, `\d+` will match the percentage (without the %). I added a [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure there's no digit or `%` after the matched number.

## Every pair

If you want to keep parsing pairs of lines :

```
data = [" The first chunk of text \n 123 the stats I want (25% the percentage I want) \n The Second chunk of text \n 456 the second stats I want (50% the second percentage I want) \n The third chunk of text \n 789 the third stats I want (75% the third percentage) \n The fourth chunk of text \n 101 The fourth stats (100% the fourth percentage) \n"]

import re

lines = data[0].strip().split("\n")

# TODO: Make sure there's an even number of lines
for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
    first_line, second_line = lines[i:i + 2]

    print first_line

    digit_match = re.search('\d+(?![\d%])', second_line)
    if digit_match:
        print digit_match.group()

    percent_match = re.search('\d+%', second_line)
    if percent_match:
        print percent_match.group()
```

It outputs :

```
The first chunk of text 
123
25%
 The Second chunk of text 
456
50%
 The third chunk of text 
789
75%
 The fourth chunk of text 
101
100%
```

Comment: Thank you for that, really appreciate it! Is there a way I can apply that to more than just the first instance? I.e. my actual data contains more than 2 strings, I'd like this to do it for all of them?

Comment: @Maverick: Updated.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help!